# Hybris convert OrderModel to CartModel

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

I have the following requirement:

Any user should be able to restore from My Account/Order History page the entries of any order to the active cart, so I want to know if there is any OOTB mechanism or a way to convert a OrderModel to CartModel or to merge the entries from an Order to the current cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, We can convert Order model to cart model.

There is an OOB class named **DefaultCartService.java**

Call the following method in a custom class or strategy

```
CartModel cartModel = cartService.clone(getTypeService().getComposedTypeForClass(CartModel.class),
            getTypeService().getComposedTypeForClass(CartEntryModel.class), order, keyGenerator.generate().toString());
```

*Here is the method in Detail:*

Parameters:

orderType - type of newly created cart

entryType - type of cart entry of newly created cart

original - original order

code - code of created cart

```
@Override
public CartModel clone(final ComposedTypeModel orderType, final ComposedTypeModel entryType,
                       final AbstractOrderModel original,
                       final String code)
{

    return (CartModel) getCloneAbstractOrderStrategy().clone(orderType, entryType, original, code, CartModel.class,
            CartEntryModel.class);
}
```

To get the cart entries (converted) from Order can be achieved using **CloneAbstractOrderStrategy.java**

```
List<CartEntryModel> cartEntries = cloneOrderStrategy.cloneEntries(getTypeService().getComposedTypeForClass(CartEntryModel.class), orderModel)
```

So, for Cloning Order to cart and its vice versa can be achieved by **CloneAbstractOrderStrategy.java**.

Please take a look of the class for better understanding!